# Force on a crash test dummy during a crumple zone experiment

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, collision

So in high school physics class, we had to do an experiment where you had a cart with a dummy that went down a ramp (constant height) into a block, where it would stop and you'd measure the distance that the dummy was flung from the point of impact. The experiment was the repeated, but there was a crumple zone on the front of the car (the mass change was negligible so for all the trials, there was constant mass).

So the question is, what is the force upon the dummy as the cart impacts with the block (not the total force of the cart-block impact, just upon the dummy)?

Would force just be *F = ma*, and the only changing variable is *a*, since the crumple zone is reducing the acceleration? That's what I was thinking it would be, but it feels like it would be something different.

Thanks

(Also, if this is classed as one of those questions where theres 'not enough effort done' and therefore it gets closed, sorry about that. I've tried loads of stuff but I want to try and keep this concise)

Comment: The precise experimental arrangement is not clear to me. Is the dummy just sitting on the cart or is there a back rest for the dummy? How does the result you get with the crumple zone compare with the result when there was no crumple zone?

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. The dummy is just sitting on the cart, with a tiny amount of blu tack holding it down (not enough to affect the motion in anyway).

Answer (score 0):

There is no force on the dummy.  The dummy is "flung from the point of impact" only because the cart hits the block, and decelerates, while the dummy is not, and stays in motion.  There might be some residual frictional force between the cart and the dummy at impact, but this is likely small.